# "Run on login" registry key not executing

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, windows-registry, login

I have the registry key `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` set to put the dual monitors into clone mode whenever a user logs in.

The data value I have currently set is `"C:\Windows\System32\DisplaySwitch.exe" /clone`

I'm working in a Group Policy isolated environment and the computer will correctly go into clone mode when I log in with my account (Domain Admin), but logging in with the generic Domain User account will leave the monitors in extended mode. It's not a permissions issue, I can run the `DisplaySwitch.exe /clone` from the command line fine. There's also nothing in the login script that would (blatantly) disable the key.

Are there anything other possible reasons that this would be ignored during login?

Comment: Why don't you just create a .bat file to make the modification when the user logs into their profile as scheduled task?

Comment: Did you use `Current\Version` as written in your post or `CurrentVersion` which is correct?

Comment: Whoops, that was a typo on my part, I used the correct CurrentVersion.

Comment: If perhaps for some reason it's trying to reach the 64-bit part of the registry: `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`? Also, for users, perhaps Windows is making the new domain-user profile from copying a template that doesn't include that? I know you said HKLM, but check to see (Google it) if your user-profile-template is a user who currently isn't working.

Comment: If you check with Autoruns http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx, is your entry shown?

Comment: Thomas, thanks for that program! It turns out that the "Group Policy free" environment wasn't quite free of it. There was an issue where it was booting in clone mode and causing a conflict between the registry command and the extended mode being set by the OU. I was able to solve the issue by saving the image in extended mode so the `DisplaySwitch.exe` would run regardless.